# Sending pdf through php mail function gives opening error

Tags: php, pdf

I am attaching an pdf file but the attachment is not opening at mail.
Its giving following *error* on mail server

> Expected: application/pdf (.pdf); found: application/x-empty

*I have following code snippet*

```
<?php
       $from='test1@domain.com';
       $to = 'test@domain.com'; 
    //define the subject of the email 
       $subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
      $message='Startendday reports' ;
    //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
    //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
       $file = file_get_contents('file.pdf');
       $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
       $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));  //unique identifier
       $file_name='file.pdf';

       //standard mail headers
       $header = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
       $header .= "Reply-To: ".$to. "\r\n";
       $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

       //declare multiple kinds of email (plain text + attch)
       $header .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";

       //plain txt part

       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
       $header .= $message. "\r\n\r\n";

       //attch part
       $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Type:application/octet-stream; name=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
       $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"\r\n\r\n";
       $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";  //chucked up 64 encoded attch

       //sending the mail - message is not here, but in the header in a multi part
       if(mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
       echo "success";
       }else {
           echo "fail";
       }

?>
```

Please help me out

Comment: Check Content-Type as application/pdf

Comment: Already done, but same error

Comment: test your code by attaching plain text file

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND i tried for text file but getting same error

Comment: What i found is, There are 2 Content-Type in your code. and is $filename blank?

Comment: It was a mistake that i used `file_get_contents` twice.Now its working by removing one of them.